# How to fix Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Syntax error on token "rs"

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me what is the compilation error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     Syntax error on token "rs", delete this token   The method
>   getString(int) is undefined for the type String
>   at SelectTest.main"

in the below java code

```
//SelectTest.java
import java.sql.*;
public class SelectTest1
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oradsn","System","123");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select*from student");
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "rs.getString(3));
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a `+` is missing before `rs.getString(3)`, please use some IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last rs.getString(3) you forget '+'

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" " +rs.getString(3));
```